# How to use a function in a branch of GitLab

Tags: r, gitlab, branch

On GitLab, I build a branch from the master branch of a package that has many functions (Rstudio). I could use the code in master branch through install_git(),install_gitlab().
However, how can I access the package in the branch that is not master branch? What should I write in the code?

Answer (score 0):

For `devtools::install_github`, you can use the `repo` argument with the following syntax: `username/repo[/subdir][@ref|#pull]`, as per the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.6/topics/install_github).